# Prove the following identity (gamma function)

Tags: gamma-function

Prove the following identity

$$\sum _{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{i} \binom{\alpha}{i} = \frac{\Gamma (k+1-\alpha)}{\Gamma(1-\alpha) \Gamma(k+1)}$$

I tried to expand the left side

$$\binom{\alpha}{0} - \binom{\alpha}{1} + \binom{\alpha}{2} - \binom{\alpha}{3} + \binom{\alpha}{4} -  \;\;\;... $$

$$ = \left [ \binom{\alpha}{0} + \binom{\alpha}{2} + \binom{\alpha}{4} +   \;\;\;...\;\; \right ] -  \left [ \binom{\alpha}{1} + \binom{\alpha}{3} + \binom{\alpha}{5} +   \;\;\;...\;\; \right ]
$$

but I couldn't simplify it. Any help?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ an integer?

Comment: @draks... $\alpha \in {\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}}$

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to rewrite

$$
(-1)^k = \binom{-1}{k}
$$

and then apply Vandermonde identity. Note the numerator is just $(k+ \alpha)!$ and the second term in the denominator $k!$

Comment: The numerator is $(k−α)!$. Right?

Comment: the results should be $(-1)^n \binom{\alpha-1}{n}$

Comment: Would you please explain it more in your answer?

Comment: It's not answer. So I gave you $-1$.